# Using Underscore to check own property

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

Used `Underscore` to check if the `global` object owns `parseInt` function on `Nodejs` console,

```
U = require('underscore')

U.contains(U.keys(global), 'parseInt') // false

U.has(global, 'parseInt') // true
```

Why did it give contrary results above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns the object properties that have their descriptors marked `enumerable`. In this case, `parseInt` is not enumerable:

e.g.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(global, 'parseInt')
```

is

```
{
    "writable":true,
    "enumerable":false,
    "configurable":true,
    "value": function parseInt(){ ...}
}
```